# While Ajax JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"../connect/post/infoClienteTask.php",
    data:'infoClienteTask='+fantasy,                
    success:function(responseData){
        console.log(responseData);          
           $(".historic-cliente").html('<li class="list-group-item">'+responseData.Project+' - '+responseData.Delivery+'</li>');        
    }
});
```

Que ao clicar em uma lista de clientes, ele mostra todo o histórico do cliente, mas com esse código eu só consigo achar o primeiro da busca.

No PHP eu tenho os seguintes códigos.

POST:

```
header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' );    

$selInfoClienteTasks= new Tasks();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    $fantasy = $_POST['infoClienteTask'];   
    $stInfoClienteTasks = $selInfoClienteTasks->selectInfoClienteTask($fantasy);

    echo json_encode($stInfoClienteTasks);

    exit();
}
```

SELECT:

```
public function selectInfoClienteTask($fantasy){
        try {           
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT tasks.*, DATE_FORMAT( tasks.Delivery , '%d/%m/%Y' ) as Delivery FROM Tasks WHERE CompanyFantasy = '$fantasy'");
            $stmt->execute();           
            return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        }catch (PDOException $exception){
            header("Location: ./error.php?err=Unable-to-find-info");
            echo 'Error: '.$excption->getMessage();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Preciso fazer um **While**/**Foreach**/**For** neste Ajax para continuar buscando até achar todos as informações, alguém tem uma ideia?

Comment: O que dá esse `console.log(responseData);`? ou melhor: `console.log(JSON.stringify(responseData));`

Comment: Todos os dados correspondente da tabela do cliente em questão, mas existe duas tarefas para o mesmo cliente, mas só aparece a primeira.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça as seguintes alterações no seu código:

**Select:**

```
public function selectInfoClienteTask($fantasy){
    try {           
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT tasks.*, DATE_FORMAT( tasks.Delivery , '%d/%m/%Y' ) as Delivery FROM Tasks WHERE CompanyFantasy = '$fantasy'");
        $stmt->execute();           
        $data = array();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $data[] = array('Project' => $row['Project'], 'Delivery' => $row['Delivery']);
        }

        return $data;

    }catch (PDOException $exception){
        header("Location: ./error.php?err=Unable-to-find-info");
        // Removi as linhas na sequencia pois se você faz o redirect nada na sequencia será executado
    }
}
```

**Ajax:**

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"../connect/post/infoClienteTask.php",
    data:'infoClienteTask='+fantasy,                
    success:function(responseData){
        $('.historic-cliente').html('');
        console.log(responseData);   
           $.each(responseData, function(i, item) {
               $(".historic-cliente").append('<li class="list-group-item">'+responseData[i].Project+' - '+responseData[i].Delivery+'</li>');   
           });​  
    }
});
```

Comment: Com a parte do PHP apareceu os dois dados do mesmo cliente, mas na hora de imprimir, ele só paga o ultimo dado inserido.

Comment: Desculpe, esqueci de alterar para utilizar o método correto, corrigi agora!

Comment: Fiz uma pequena mudança `$('.historic-cliente').html('');`,  antes do `$.each`, para limpar, se não ele sempre vai adicionar.

Comment: Perfeito, adicionei também!

Answer (score 1):

Acesse o índice do seu response através de um *for*:

```
responseData[i].Project
```

O *foreach* também é possível, precisaria ver qual o conteúdo desde response para montar um codigo de exemplo para você.
Utilize o código passado pelo amigo Sergio (console.log(JSON.stringify(responseData));) para obtê-lo.